# Validating an Equal Object Json in a List Array C#

Tags: arrays, json, .net, list, json.net

I'm a beginner and I'm having problems validating an object with the same value as a list inside an Array. The problem seems simple but I'm having trouble manipulating the objects.
I have an Array called ApprovedLevels which contains some User objects, they are the "approval levels".
However, there is a bug where sometimes the frontend sends us the same value inside the "Ordination" object and what I need to do in the backend here is that whenever the Ordination value is equal to one in the list of ApprovalLevels it needs to add +1, make some increment on that received equal Ordination value, or jump to the next value in the list.

Here is the Json I get:

```
"ApprovalLevels":[
        {
            "Ordination": 10,
            "Users": [
                {
                    "UserId": 116
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Ordination": 10,
            "Users": [
                {
                    "UserId": 118
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
```

And here below I'll put all the code I tried to do so far, the technology I'm using is .net framework 3 and to manipulate, deserialize the objects I'm using newtonsoft too.
In the code, this Ordination is done by the user of the list that receives:

```
JArray newLevelsArray = JArray.FromObject(levelsArray.Where(l => l["Id"] == null).ToList());

    foreach (JObject newLevelObject in newLevelsArray)
    {
        BusinessRuleApprovalLevel newLevel = PloomesUtils.JsonToObject<BusinessRuleApprovalLevel>(newLevelObject);

        JArray ordinationObj = JArray.FromObject(levelsArray.Where(o => o["Ordination"] != null).ToList());
     
        newLevel.Ordination = (int)ordinationObj;

        JObject equalOrdination = levelsArray.FirstOrDefault(eo => eo["Ordination"] != null && (int)eo["Ordination"] == newLevel.Ordination) as JObject;

        if (JObject.Equals(ordinationObj, equalOrdination))
        {
            BusinessRuleApprovalLevel deletedOrdination = BusinessRuleApprovalLevel.Find(newLevel.Ordination);
            BusinessRuleApprovalLevel.Remove(deletedOrdination);
            SaveChanges();
        }

        newLevel.Ordination = (int)ordinationObj;
        newLevel.BusinessRuleId = ruleId;

        BusinessRuleApprovalLevel.Add(newLevel);

        SaveChanges();

        if (newLevelObject.Property("Users") != null && newLevelObject["Users"].Type != JTokenType.Null)
            UpdateApprovalLevelUsers(newLevel.Id, (JArray)newLevelObject["Users"]);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry , but I cant see the same value inside the "Ordination", I can't even see what insides ordination has. Can you pls explain by putting two examples: what you have  and what you want.

Comment: This "ApprovalLevels" array is already the example, you will see that inside the object "Ordination" contains the value 10 and then the next value with a different user is also with the value 10. I needed to do was to deal with this case where both users contain the same "Ordination" value.  I hope I explained it better and thanks for answering

Comment: Thanks , Can you post the second example what you wnant pls? Your explanation contains too many letters, I will never be able to finish reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its very confusing manipulating JObject and JArray, so my first tip its to you define objects and convert it, so you can manipulate it easily.

I made some lab with my understandment:

First, I define the objects:

```
public class Root {
    public List<ApprovaLevel> ApprovalLevels {get; set;}
}
public class ApprovaLevel {
    public int Ordination {get; set;}
    public List<User> Users {get; set;}
}
public class User {
    public int UserId {get; set;}
}
```

And then I can play with conversion and treatments:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var teste1 = GetFinalObject("{\"ApprovalLevels\":[ {\"Ordination\": 10,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 116}]},{\"Ordination\": 10,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 118}]}]}");     
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(teste1));
    
    var teste2 = GetFinalObject("{\"ApprovalLevels\":[ {\"Ordination\": 10,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 116}]},{\"Ordination\": 10,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 119}]},{\"Ordination\": 10,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 118}]}]}");     
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(teste2));
    
    
    var teste3 = GetFinalObject("{\"ApprovalLevels\":[ {\"Ordination\": 10,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 116}]},{\"Ordination\": 10,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 119}]},{\"Ordination\": 10,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 118}]},{\"Ordination\": 11,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 118}]},{\"Ordination\": 11,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 118}]},{\"Ordination\": 13,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 118}]},{\"Ordination\": 21,\"Users\": [{\"UserId\": 118}]}]}");     
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(teste3));
}
public static object GetFinalObject(string json)
{
    Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
    root.ApprovalLevels = root.ApprovalLevels.OrderBy(b => b.Ordination).ThenBy(u => string.Join("|", u.Users.Select(us => us.UserId))).ToList();
    
    foreach (var level in root.ApprovalLevels)
    {
        var originalLevelsWithSameOrdination = root.ApprovalLevels.Where(a => a.Ordination == level.Ordination).ToArray();
        if(originalLevelsWithSameOrdination.Count() > 1)
        {
            var previousOrdination = level.Ordination;
            foreach (var item in originalLevelsWithSameOrdination.Skip(1))
            {
                item.Ordination = ++previousOrdination;
            }
        }           
    }
    return root;
}
```

My output:

```
{"ApprovalLevels":[{"Ordination":10,"Users":[{"UserId":116}]},{"Ordination":11,"Users":[{"UserId":118}]}]}
{"ApprovalLevels":[{"Ordination":10,"Users":[{"UserId":116}]},{"Ordination":11,"Users":[{"UserId":118}]},{"Ordination":12,"Users":[{"UserId":119}]}]}
{"ApprovalLevels":[{"Ordination":10,"Users":[{"UserId":116}]},{"Ordination":11,"Users":[{"UserId":118}]},{"Ordination":12,"Users":[{"UserId":119}]},{"Ordination":13,"Users":[{"UserId":118}]},{"Ordination":14,"Users":[{"UserId":118}]},{"Ordination":15,"Users":[{"UserId":118}]},{"Ordination":21,"Users":[{"UserId":118}]}]}
```

Anyway, I think you should also understand what is happening on frontend, because you are assuming a new order without user's consentment